# symfony server start - logs multiple times

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've been using symfony server for development for a while now (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html), and everything used to be fine. But lately it started logging messages multiple times.

Ex.

```
$ ▶ symfony server:start
Tailing Web Server log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/home/vitals/.symfony/log/87e0a0bd6be99c02b64da0c88ffbc73128fb48bf/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
```

Is taling same log file tens of times. And of course whenever I do something I get output like:

```
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57810 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57818 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Nov 19 13:18:38 2020] 127.0.0.1:57814 Accepted
```

Is like is opening on multiple ports instead of one. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like you're not the only one dealing with this https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/356

Comment: Yeah, this is better dealt with as bug report with the maintainer. Follow that issue, it will get handled at some point.

Comment: can you post that as an answer pls? :) would like to accept and may help other ppl.